# Kafka producer poor performance

Tags: apache-kafka, messaging, producer-consumer, kafka-producer-api, spring-kafka

I have an issue with kafka producer. Actually I am using spring kafka, and sending messages through KafkaTemplate leke this:

```
DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<K, V> defaultKafkaProducerFactory = new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(producerParams);
KafkaTemplate kafkaTemplate = new KafkaTemplate<>(defaultKafkaProducerFactory);
RecordMetadata recordMetadata = kafkaTemplate.send(record).get().getRecordMetadata();
```

Problem is that sometimes send message takes 4-20 sec. There a lot of messages that takes 100 ms to send. So I have few questions:

1. Is there any correlation between message size and throughput, what is the relation?
2. What should I check firstly, maybe I have't done tuning well, any direction?

Comment: Maybe your sender has batch.size set and and a high linger.ms?

Comment: linger.ms = 0
ack = all

Comment: I see that sometimes CPU on machine with application reaches 70-85%, kafka on the same machine. Maybe it is because of this.

How can I check that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, actually problem was in machines, cpu was to high, there were logs in Cloudera manager

> Detected pause in JVM or host machine (e.g. a stop the world GC, or
>   JVM not scheduled): paused approximately 4332ms: no GCs detected.
>
> Detected pause in JVM or host machine (e.g. a stop the world GC, or
>   JVM not scheduled): paused approximately 10827ms: GC pool
>   'ConcurrentMarkSweep' had collection(s): count=1 time=11107ms

When I run the same on machine with 8 cores - problem is gone. one more thing that was recommended is increasing **Java Heap Size of Broker**

Answer (score 0):

If you have a huge amount of Data then Kafka producer requires a Performance Tunning. In this case, its better to configure  **batch.size**,  **linger.ms** & **buffer.memory**. Normally, in the kafka the batch.size default configuration is 16K bytes. To improve the Performance, just increase the batch.size.

```
props.put(ProducerConfig.BATCH_SIZE_CONFIG, 16_384 * 4);
    // Send with little bit buffering
    props.put(ProducerConfig.LINGER_MS_CONFIG, 200);    
  //Use Snappy compression for batch compression.
    props.put(ProducerConfig.COMPRESSION_TYPE_CONFIG, "snappy");
```

With the above configurations the performance must be good. More details you will find in the below link.

[Kafka Performance](http://cloudurable.com/blog/kafka-tutorial-kafka-producer-advanced-java-examples/index.html)